# How do I open a windows 10 bitlocked ssd with a pin on a windows 8.1 pro computer?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

Drive was a boot drive with windows 10 and bitlocked (automatically? dont recall doing it) and was secured by a pin and fingerprint. This was from a thinkpad with a TPM module.
Computer is not part of an active directory domain so my googling has not been very helpful.

I dont have the original laptop, and am trying to open this on a different laptop (without tpm) with windows 8.1 pro and no fingerprint reader.

When I attempt to open it, I get the error

```
There are no supported protectors on this drive. This drive can't be unlocked.
```

What can I do? Do I need access to the original TPM chip? or just a laptop with one?

some manage-bde info:

```
    BitLocker Drive Encryption:
    Volume D: [Label Unknown]
    [Data Volume]
    Size:                 Unknown GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Unknown
    Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%
    ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070057):
    The parameter is incorrect.
```

Tried my recovery key, I'm not 100% sure it was the latest one made for this install though:

```
manage-bde -unlock e: -RecoveryKey "keypath"
```

resulted in:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while attempting to read the key from disk.
```

Running this with my pin:

```
manage-bde -unlock D: -pw
```

resulted in:

```
ERROR: The password failed to unlock volume D:.
```

also running this: `manage-bde -protectors D: -get`

Gave this:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.3.9600
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume D: [Label Unknown]
All Key Protectors

ERROR: No key protectors found.
```